# Separate a mysql array into a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a problem with MySQL query. I'm trying select products info over the order products list, but it are selecting only the first record, being that the products list is a array.
Example: being orders.itens = "10,11,12,13", the "IN" selects only the first ID, "10". How I do to select all ID's, something that sounds like implode function in PHP?

```
SELECT
    orders.id,
    products.name,
    products.price
FROM 
    orders,
    products
WHERE
    products.id IN (orders.itens)
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to give the values seperately in th `IN` clause like `IN ("10","11","12","13")`

Comment: And how I do to separate the values into a MySQL query?

Comment: How are you getting the values for in clause

Comment: I'm using a multiple mysql query, so I can't use any PHP functions.. The orders.itens row is exactly how I posted: "10,11,12,13". I need a MySQL function to divide..

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a join:

```
SELECT o.id, p.name, p.price
FROM orders o join
     products p
     on find_in_set(p.id, o.items) > 0;
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to optimize this query.  You should created an association/junction table, probably called `OrderProducts` that contains one row for each product in an order.

Comment: But if I'll create a row for each product, the table will be giant

Comment: @CristianAugusto . . . This is how databases are designed to be used.  What is "giant" anyway?  Unless you are talking about billions of rows, then your table is not "giant".

Comment: But if a order have 10 products, how I do to create a row for each product?

Comment: @CristianAugusto . . . You need to re-organize your database so you have an `OrderProducts` table.  Such as table would have rows like (Order=1, Product=a), (Order=1, Product=b), and (Order=1, Product=c).  A separate row for each product in an order.  Google "junction table" or "association table" -- you'll get lots of hits with lots of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need something like this

```
select CONCAT('"',CONCAT(Replace("10,11,12,13", ',', '","'),'"')) as str
```

And use this as the value for in clause